# How can I make the selenium chromedriver make wait until it maximizes the window?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been messing around with python/selenium a bit, now I got to use the "try" method. I want the driver to wait until it maximized the window, and then go on with the code. At the beginning it just went on executing all scripts and the chrome window got maximized whilst executing it, which looked pretty weird.
Anyways I hope you can help me,
Have a good day y'all ;))

Ah, here's the code: (And the error message beneath it)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Anyone\Desktop\Python\chromedriver.exe')

print("Automation Started, please hold on.")

driver.get("https://blablabla")

try:
    recap = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.WebDriverException(driver.maximize_window())

    )
finally:
    driver.forward()
```

And here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anyone/PycharmProjects/blebleble/blablabla.py", line 17, in <module>
    EC.WebDriverException(driver.maximize_window())
  File "C:\Users\Anyone\PycharmProjects\blablabla\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'WebDriverException' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wait for the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* to open first and then **maximize** it.

Instead, add the argument **`start-maximized`** and configure the driver, so the *Google Chrome Browsing Context* opens up **maximized** using the solution below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://blablabla")
```

Answer (score 0):

After making driver object use the below code:-

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

and remove the try/finally block.